# One as Subscript and Supersripts

Tags: subscript, index

I am trying writing code with a lots of symbols and their products.
There is an issue with the appearance of "1" as an index. e.g.

Subscript[[Delta], 1 n]

Why "1" does not appear in subscript?

Comment: Because the implied multiplication of 1 times n returns n to the Subscript function. Use a string instead ("1 n").

Comment: I use `Subscript[\[Delta], 1, n]` in such cases. That is, divide 1 and n by a comma. This works well.

Comment: Or `Subscript[\[Delta], Row[{1, n}]]` or `Subscript[\[Delta], Row[{1, \[ThinSpace], n}]]`